# Nagios notification mail after that a service failed for more than N minutes

Tags: monitoring, nagios

like in the title
I would like to receive the alert from nagios only if a service
keep failing for more than 10 minutes in a row.
Which macro or parameters I've to change?
I am on debian 6 and my nagios version is 3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. You should refer to the [Object Definitions docs](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html) and the [State Types docs](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/statetypes.html).

The length of time until a service notification goes out is a factor of **check_interval**, **retry_interval**, **max_check_attempts**, (and possibly first_notification_delay). There may also be escalations to consider.

Simplistically, if your check_interval is 5 and your retry_interval is 1, a max_check_attempts of 5 will get you close to "more than 10 minutes in a row".

Comment: In fact Keith I've changed those 3 parameters and now I got a notification only if the service is down for more than 15 minutes.